# What is the cheapest and easiest way to cool 2 liters of water without using ice or a fridge?

Tags: cooling

Working on a new prototype and I would need the answer to this:

What is the cheapest and easiest way to cool 2 liters of water without using ice or a fridge?

Comment: What have you tried so we don't waste our time on repeats where you say "Oh, already tried that"...

Comment: How hot does it start? How cold do you need? How fast? The cheapest way to cool some hot water is to leave it alone in the air...

Comment: There are too many possible answers due to so little explanation and constraints.  How long can it take?  What *do* you have at your disposal?  From what temperature to what other temperature?  Do you have additional water that is expendable?  What is the overall purpose?

Answer (score 1):

-Fill in a vase with clean cool silt and let the water drain through it.

- Spill it on a cool stone slab sloping down to a container.
- Run it through a car radiator.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "Zeer pot", commonly used for keeping wine chilled.

A ceramic pot which is soaked in water and as the water evaporates from the surface it cools the interior - only issue can be that if the ambient humidity is very high it does not work so well...

Also used in hot climates to cool rooms...

A link to one description : https://practicalaction.org/zeer-pot-fridge

Comment: This process of evaporative works well when the humidity is low.  When I lived in Phoenix, AZ, I had a [swamp cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler) that lowered the temperature from maybe 110 F outside to 80 F inside.  The bad news is it does not work so swell when the humidity is higher.  In the late summer when the humidity was up, I had to break down and use the refrigeration a/c.

Comment: @user1683793 I mentioned that in my answer about the issue of humidity being high...